Why is my convolution kernel leaving streaks of gray when filtering grayscale images read with OpenCV?
I am designing a 2d convolution (blurring) program that will receive grayscale images as input and perform the convolution algorithm in parallel with CUDA C++. My Filter (kernel) is a 5 x 5 2D matrix with all values initialized as float values of 1.0f/25.0f. Currently I am trying to find an edge case I am missing either in my CUDA kernel or when I am launching CUDA kernel based on the calculated Grid and block dimensions. I am intentionally not handling the 2 pixel border. I am not receiving any CUDA errors just an incorrect result from running with the attach file tree-grayscale.jpg
Here is the Minimal, Reproducible Example
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<cmath>
#include<math.h>
#include<cstdio>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define FILTER_RADIUS 2
const float F_h[2 * FILTER_RADIUS + 1][2 * FILTER_RADIUS + 1] = {
    {1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25},
    {1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25},
    {1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25},
    {1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25},
    {1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25, 1.0f / 25}
};
__constant__ float F[2*FILTER_RADIUS+1][2*FILTER_RADIUS+1];

#define CHECK(call) { \
    const cudaError_t cuda_ret = call; \
    if(cuda_ret != cudaSuccess){\
        printf("Error: %s:%d, ", __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        printf("code: %d, reason:%s\n", cuda_ret, cudaGetErrorString(cuda_ret)); \
        exit(-1); \
    } \
}

double myCPUTimer(){
    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
    return ((double)tp.tv_sec + (double)tp.tv_usec/1.0e6);
}


__global__ void blurImage_Kernel(unsigned char * Pout, unsigned char * Pin, unsigned int width, unsigned int height){
    int outCol = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int outRow = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (outCol < width && outRow < height) {
        float Pvalue = 0.0f;
        int inRow = 0, inCol = 0;
        int condition = 2*FILTER_RADIUS + 1;

        for(int fRow = 0; fRow < condition; fRow++){
            for(int fCol = 0; fCol < condition; fCol++){
                inRow = outRow - FILTER_RADIUS + fRow;
                inCol = outCol - FILTER_RADIUS + fCol;
                if(inRow >= 0 && inRow < height && inCol >= 0 && inCol < width){
                    Pvalue += F[fRow][fCol] * (float) Pin[inRow* width + inCol];
                }
            }
        }

        Pout[outRow*width + outCol] = (unsigned char) min(max(Pvalue, 0.0f), 255.0f);
    }
}

void blurImage_d(cv::Mat Pout_Mat_h, cv::Mat Pin_Mat_h, unsigned int nRows, unsigned int nCols){

    printf("\n\nblurImage_Kernel: \n");

    // (1) allocate device memory for arrays p_d
    unsigned char *Pin_d, *Pout_d;
    double start_time_malloc = myCPUTimer();
    cudaMalloc((void**) &Pin_d, sizeof(unsigned char) * nRows * nCols);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &Pout_d, sizeof(unsigned char) * nRows * nCols);
    double end_time_malloc = myCPUTimer();
    double elapsed_time_malloc = end_time_malloc - start_time_malloc;

    printf("\tcudaMalloc: \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t%f s\n", elapsed_time_malloc);

    // (2) copy image matrix Pin_h to device memory Pin_d
    unsigned char * Pin_h = Pin_Mat_h.data;
    double start_time_memcpy = myCPUTimer();
    cudaMemcpy(Pin_d, Pin_h, sizeof(unsigned char)*nCols*nRows, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    double end_time_memcpy = myCPUTimer();
    double elapsed_time_memcpy = end_time_memcpy - start_time_memcpy;

    printf("\tcudaMemcpy: \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t%f s\n", elapsed_time_memcpy);

    // (3) call kernel to launch a grid of threads to perform the image convolution on GPU
    dim3 gridDim((nRows + 32 - 1) / 32, (nCols + 32 - 1) / 32);
    dim3 blockDim(32, 32);

    double start_time = myCPUTimer();
    blurImage_Kernel<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(Pout_d, Pin_d, nRows, nCols);
    CHECK(cudaGetLastError());
    CHECK(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    double end_time = myCPUTimer();
    double elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;

    printf("\tblurImage_Kernel<<<(%d, %d, 1), (%d, %d, 1)>>>: \t\t\t%f s\n", (nCols + 32 - 1) / 32, (nRows + 32 - 1) / 32, 32, 32, elapsed_time);

    // (4) Copy the result data from device memory of array Pout_d to host memory of array Pout_h
    Pout_Mat_h = cv::Mat::zeros(nRows, nCols, CV_8U);
    unsigned char * Pout_h = Pout_Mat_h.data;
    double start_time_memcpy2 = myCPUTimer();
    cudaMemcpy(Pout_h, Pout_d, sizeof(unsigned char)*nCols*nRows, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    double end_time_memcpy2 = myCPUTimer();
    double elapsed_time_memcpy2 = end_time_memcpy2 - start_time_memcpy2;

    printf("\tcudaMemcpy: \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t%f s\n\n", elapsed_time_memcpy2);

    double total_elapsed_time = elapsed_time_malloc + elapsed_time_memcpy + elapsed_time + elapsed_time_memcpy2;

    printf("Total elapsed time for convolution without tiling: %f s\n", total_elapsed_time);

    // (5) free device memory of Pin_d and Pout_d
    cudaFree(Pin_d);
    cudaFree(Pout_d);

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char* file_name = argv[1];
    printf("Blurring file: \"%s\"\n", file_name);

    Mat Pin_Mat_h = cv::imread(file_name, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    unsigned int nRows = Pin_Mat_h.rows, nCols = Pin_Mat_h.cols, nChannels = Pin_Mat_h.channels();

    printf("\n\n\n Dimension of image: %d %d \n\n\n", nRows, nCols);

    // for comparison purpose, implement a CUDA kernel but without tiling
    Mat Pout_Mat_h(nRows, nCols, CV_8UC1);
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(F, F_h, (2*FILTER_RADIUS+1)*(2*FILTER_RADIUS+1)*sizeof(float));
    blurImage_d(Pout_Mat_h, Pin_Mat_h, nRows, nCols);

    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    std::tm* now = std::localtime(&t);
    std::ostringstream oss_kernel;
    oss_kernel << "blurred_kernel("
        << (now->tm_year + 1900) << '-'
        << (now->tm_mon + 1) << '-'
        << now->tm_mday << '_'
        << now->tm_sec
        << ").jpg";
    
    std::string filename_kernel = oss_kernel.str();
    imwrite(filename_kernel, Pout_Mat_h);

    return 0;
}

Here is the makeFile I am using to compile the code
# Makefile for compiling convolution with OpenCV and CUDA

# Set variables for OpenCV and CUDA paths
OPENCV_INCLUDE = $(OPENCV_HOME)/include/opencv4
OPENCV_LIB = $(OPENCV_HOME)/lib64

# Specify the compiler
NVCC = nvcc

# Compiler flags
CFLAGS = -I $(OPENCV_INCLUDE) -L $(OPENCV_LIB) -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc

# Output binary
TARGET = convolution

# Source file
SRC = con.cu

# Default target
all: $(TARGET)

# Rule to compile the convolution binary
$(TARGET): $(SRC)
    module load opencv/4.9.0.x86_64 && \
    $(NVCC) -o $(TARGET) $(SRC) $(CFLAGS)

# Clean up build artifacts
clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET)
    rm -f blurred*.jpg


NOTE: module load opencv/4.9.0.x86_64 must be ran before building compiling code. I am running this on NCSA delta GPU computing node.
To run ./convolution tree-grayscale.jpg
attached is the image I am having problems with

here is the output image


What does it look like after the convolution? One thing I can see is that the sum of weights will not be 1 for the outer 2-pixel-thick border, so the border pixels will tend to be darker. You should sum the weights that passed the condition and use Pvalue / weight_total.

It is having a gray diagonal streak from the top left corner to the bottom right corner. of the original image. I am intentionally not handling the 2 pixel border.

If you can add the image in the post, that would be helpful. Seeing the artifacts instead of a reading a text description of it might point to more specific issues.

attached! sorry about that

I think I see the issue. The kernel takes width, height, but you provide nRows, nCols. width should be nCols, and height should be nRows. Since the image is 345x346, there's a small offset that might affect the final result.

Yes that's it! It's always the smallest things. Thank you.

You are also ignoring that the matrix could have strides (Mat::step) that are different from its dimensions.
